# Удалить энв переменную в рантайм

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Spring Boot actuator - есть выставленный урл /env, по которому можно посмотреть environment variables (порт, base path, какие то кастомные переменные)

Есть ли возможность удалить переменную во время выполнения?

Такая ситуация: в классе указана переменная:

```
 @Value("my.custom.bool:true")
boolean param;
```

Но когда я делаю запрос GET https://.../env на эндпоинт актуатора, он возвращает мне список всех существующих переменных в котором нет ... моего парама!)

Чудеса) Как такое возможно?

Upd: значение по дебагу false,по поведению тоже. Класс отмечен как компонент

Answer (score 0):

Вы неправильно понимаете, как работает `@Value("my.custom.bool:true")`.

Вы, похоже, воспринимаете эту аннотацию, как способ задания параметра конфигурации в spring. Но на самом деле это только использование параметра конфигурации в конкретном месте, но при этом, если параметр не задан (как у вас), то используется значение по умолчанию (`true`).

Может показаться, что нет разницы. Но разница есть, она в том, что `@Value` не устанавливает значение параметра в окружение (по-этому вы этого параметра там и не видите, в окружении он не установлен).

Comment: Да дело в том что он фолс((

Comment: Ответ на вопрос, что сформулирован я написал. То что параметр `false` - это совсем другой вопрос :) Вы случайно не вручную создаете объект? Т.е. в обход sping-a. Это частая ошибка, в этом случае переменная получит значение по-умолчанию (false), а аннотации `@Value` не будут обрабатываться, т.к. не спринг создавал объект, а именно spring при создании бина обрабатывает аннотации и устанавливает значение.

Comment: Да не, вроде все на месте. Компонентом отмечен

Comment: Кстати, почему "my.custom.bool" без доллара и фигурных скобок? Это выражение не трактуется как параметр вообще, а просто строка.

Comment: Это образно) там все на месте,) оно работало раньше, но потом перестало, а измений никаких нет

Comment: Тут же есть - @ConfigurationProperties("prefix") , может быть дело в этом?